# multiple scenarios in one feature files - how to clear the item added at first scenario?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I am scripting the test on todo app.

the expected should be first scenarios has
"First todo item #1"

then second scenario added
"Next todo item"

in total 2 items only.

but actual result i got 3 items.

is that the way i written scenario wrong?

```
  Scenario: Add first item
    Given my todo list is empty
    When I add "First todo item #1"
    Then my todo list should contain:
      | First todo item #1|
    And the remaining item count should show "1 item left"

  Scenario: Add another item
    Given I have a todo list containing
      | First todo item #1 |
    When I add "Next todo item"
    Then my todo list should contain:
      | Next todo item |
      | First todo item #1 |
    And the remaining item count should show "2 items left"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each scenario should be independent. Why don't you join your scenarios? You can add [background](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background) section which is executed before each scenario:

```
  Background:
    Given my todo list is empty

  Scenario: Item addition 
    When I add "First todo item #1"
    Then my todo list should contain:
      | First todo item #1|
    And the remaining item count should show "1 item left"
    When I add "Next todo item"
    Then my todo list should contain:
      | Next todo item |
      | First todo item #1 |
    And the remaining item count should show "2 items left"

  Scenario: Item edition
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the "background"  suggestion. Any good way if i want to add total of 10 items? Is that good just one scenario and copy paste the steps?

Comment: I would create step "When I add 10 items" and inside this step I would call function behind "When I add ... "  ten times in a loop.